# How to get latitude and longitude while collecting sensor data?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on an app that collects Accelerometer, magnetometer data every 20 milliseconds and it saves the data to a csv file.

What I want to do is collect precise latitude and longitude too at the time of data collection so that I can create a heat map (eg. of house).

I am not an android expert. So, I don't know much on how to implement this feature. Is it possible to get coordinate data every 20 milliseconds during indoor data collection?

Below is my current work. Please help me with how can I get real time lat, long and save it to my csv file and what changes I should make?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener
{
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor magnetic;

    private int counter = 1;

    private boolean recording = false;
    private boolean counterOn = false;

    private float magValues[] = new float[3];

    private Context context;

    private static final int REQUESTCODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 1;

    Collection<String[]> magneticData = new ArrayList<>();

    private CsvWriter csvWriter = null;

    public static DecimalFormat DECIMAL_FORMATTER;

    TextView stateText;
    EditText fileIDEdit;

    TextView magText;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(listenerStartButton);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(listenerStopButton);

        fileIDEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        magText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        stateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        stateText.setText("Stand by");

        context = this;

        // Sensor
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        magnetic = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US);
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
        DECIMAL_FORMATTER = new DecimalFormat("#.000", symbols);

    }
    private View.OnClickListener listenerStartButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            recording = true;
            stateText.setText("Recording started");
            stateText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }
    };

    private int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private View.OnClickListener listenerStopButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(recording == true)
            {
                recording = false;

                counter = 0;

                String value = fileIDEdit.getText().toString();

                stateText.setText("Recording Stopped");
                stateText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));

                if (storagePermitted((Activity) context)){
                    csvWriter = new CsvWriter();
                    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "magnetic" + value + ".csv");
                    //File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "magnetic" + value + ".csv");

                    try {
                        csvWriter.write(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, magneticData);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File is recorded in memory.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException io) {
                        Log.d("Error", io.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nothing to save. Recording was not started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetic, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        long timeInMillisec = (new Date()).getTime() + (event.timestamp - System.nanoTime()) / 1000000L;

        if(recording) {
            float x = 0;
            float y = 0;
            float z = 0;
            double magnitude = 0;
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
                // New Code:
                x = event.values[0];
                y = event.values[1];
                z = event.values[2];
                magnitude = Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y + y)
                        + (z * z));
                //magText.setText("Magnetometer:  " + timeInMillisec+"   X= " + roundThis(event.values[0]) + "   Y= " + roundThis(event.values[1]) + "   Z= " + roundThis(event.values[2]));
                magText.setText("Magnetometer:   X= " + x + "   Y= " + y + "   Z= " + z + "  Magnitude: " + DECIMAL_FORMATTER.format(magnitude) + "\u00b5Tesla");

                Log.d("Record", "Magnetometer" + String.valueOf(counter));
                magValues = event.values;
            }
            //magneticData.add(new String[]{String.valueOf(timeInMillisec), String.valueOf(magValues[0]), String.valueOf(magValues[1]), String.valueOf(magValues[2])});
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat logLineStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:SSS", Locale.getDefault());
            //logLineStamp.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));


            magneticData.add(new String[]{logLineStamp.format(new Date(timeInMillisec)), String.valueOf(x), String.valueOf(y), String.valueOf(z), String.valueOf(magnitude)});
            counter++;
        }
    }
    // Checks if the the storage permissions are given or not by the user
    // It will request the use if not
    private static boolean storagePermitted(Activity activity){
        // Check read write permission
        Boolean readPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        Boolean writePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        if (readPermission && writePermission){
            return true;
    }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUESTCODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION);

        return false;
}
    public static float roundThis(float value){
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.floatValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

Comment: _"Is it possible to get coordinate data every 20 milliseconds during indoor data collection?"_ No, GPS won't work indoors, other methods are not very accurate and the location refresh rate probably won't be that high.

Comment: _"...what changes I should make?"_ You should add the code that gets the location. Maybe see the Android documentation [about getting location](https://developer.android.com/training/location). You'll want to request location updates and you'll need to ask for the location permission.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Thank you for answering. So, if i cannot get exact coordinates just by walking around inside my house, how can I use sensor data to create a heat map of indoor area. Is there something that I am missing out?

Comment: Because the task is to collect sensor data and create a heat map, something like this [Example](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/ob/jaf8whpykzdp.png)

Comment: Bluetooth LE beacons are sometimes used to estimate a location inside a building, but it's not very accurate and the mistake can be several meters. You'd need to have several beacons in known locations and trilaterate the device location based on the signal strengths/estimated distances.